# Define special matrix in Mathematica

Tags: matrix

Is it possible to define this matrix in mathematica when N is Odd and N is Even? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Short answer: Yes. This time, please try it yourself.

Comment: Is it ok this please:n = 7; a = 
 Array[{i, j} \[Function] 
   UnitStep[i - j] Mod[i - j, 2] 2 (2 j - 1), {n, n}]; a // TeXForm

Comment: Dear Henrik, it is different from my previous matrix....thanks

Comment: What part of this question is so different from your previous question that you can't solve it by applying the techniques you learned from the answer you previously received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use `P` rather than the reserved word `N`.

```
D1[P_]:=Table[If[OddQ[i-j]&&i>j,2(2j-1),0],{i,P},{j,P}] // MatrixForm
```

An example with `P=8` even:

[image]

An example with `P=9` odd:

[image]

Comment: Dear mjw, thanks for your response is it for N is odd or even?...

Comment: Works for both even or odd.  Please try it out.  I would post pictures (of matrices) but am at a machine that doesn't have Mathematica on it, if you could believe it!

Comment: Thanks mjw....Best regards

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: One could also use `SparseArray[]`: `With[{n = 8}, Normal[SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; i > j && OddQ[i - j] :> 2 (2 j - 1), {n, n}]]]`.